# Using an RDBMS as event sourcing storage

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

If I were using an RDBMS (e.g. SQL Server) to store event sourcing data, what might the schema look like?

I've seen a few variations talked about in an abstract sense, but nothing concrete.

For example, say one has a "Product" entity, and changes to that product could come in the form of: Price, Cost and Description. I'm confused about whether I'd:

1. Have a "ProductEvent" table, that has all the fields for a product, where each change means a new record in that table, plus "who, what, where, why, when and how" (WWWWWH) as appropriate. When cost, price or description are changed, a whole new row as added to represent the Product.
2. Store product Cost, Price and Description in separate tables joined to the Product table with a foreign key relationship. When changes to those properties occur, write new rows with WWWWWH as appropriate.
3. Store WWWWWH, plus a serialised object representing the event, in a "ProductEvent" table, meaning the event itself must be loaded, de-serialised and re-played in my application code in order to re-build the application state for a given Product.

Particularly I worry about option 2 above. Taken to the extreme, the product table would be almost one-table-per-property, where to load the Application State for a given product would require loading all events for that product from each product event table. This table-explosion smells wrong to me.

I'm sure "it depends", and while there's no single "correct answer", I'm trying to get a feel for what is acceptable, and what is totally not acceptable. I'm also aware that NoSQL can help here, where events could be stored against an aggregate root, meaning only a single request to the database to get the events to rebuild the object from, but we're not using a NoSQL db at the moment so I'm feeling around for alternatives.

Comment: In its most simple form: [Event] { AggregateId, AggregateVersion, EventPayload }. No need for the aggregate type, but you COULD optionally store it. No need for event type, but you COULD optionally store it. It's a long list of things that have happened, anything else is just optimization.

Comment: Definitely stay away from #1 and #2.  Serialize everything down to a blob and store it that way.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The event store should not need to know about the specific fields or properties of events. Otherwise every modification of your model would result in having to migrate your database (just as in good old-fashioned state-based persistence). Therefore I wouldn't recommend option 1 and 2 at all.

Below is the schema as used in [Ncqrs](https://github.com/pjvds/ncqrs). As you can see, the table "Events" stores the related data as a CLOB (i.e. JSON or XML). This corresponds to your option 3 (Only that there is no "ProductEvents" table because you only need one generic "Events" table. In Ncqrs the mapping to your Aggregate Roots happens through the "EventSources" table, where each EventSource corresponds to an actual Aggregate Root.)

```
Table Events:
    Id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    TimeStamp [datetime] NOT NULL,

    Name [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    Version [varchar](max) NOT NULL,

    EventSourceId [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    Sequence [bigint], 

    Data [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL

Table EventSources:
    Id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
    Type [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL, 
    Version [int] NOT NULL
```

The SQL persistence mechanism of [Jonathan Oliver's Event Store implementation](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore) consists basically of one table called "Commits" with a BLOB field "Payload". This is pretty much the same as in Ncqrs, only that it serializes the event's properties in binary format (which, for instance,  adds encryption support).

Greg Young recommends a similar approach, as [extensively documented on Greg's website](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/building-event-storage/).

The schema of his prototypical "Events" table reads:

```
Table Events
    AggregateId [Guid],
    Data [Blob],
    SequenceNumber [Long],
    Version [Int]
```

Comment: Nice answer! One of the main arguments I keep reading about to use EventSourcing is the ability to query the history. How am I going to make an reporting tool that is efficient in querying when all interesting data is serialized as XML or JSON? Are there any interesting articles looking for an table based solution?

Comment: @MarijnHuizendveld you probably don't want to query against the event store itself. The most common solution would be to hook up a couple of event handlers that project the events into a reporting or BI database. The replay the event history against these handlers.

Comment: @Denis Traub thanks for your answer. Why not query against the event store itself? I'm afraid it will get quite messy/intense if we have to replay the full history every time we come up with a new BI case?

Comment: I thought at some point you were supposed to also have tables besides the event store, to store data from the model in it's latest state?  And that you split the model into a read model and a write model.  The write model goes against the event store, and the event store martials updates to the read model.  The read model contains the tables that represent the entities in your system--so you can use the read model to do reporting and viewing.  I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: @theBoringCoder It sounds like you have Event Sourcing and CQRS confused or at least mashed up in your head. They are frequently found together but they are not the same thing. CQRS has you separate your read and write models while Event Sourcing has you use an event stream as the single source of truth in your application.

Comment: FYI uniqueidentifiers as PKs (and FKs) are a disaster in the making (cf. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/). Been there...

Comment: Given the table above, how would you query on the field "Description" when you store every new record in a serialized format? Say for example, I want to "SELECT Price, Cost FROM ProductEvents WHERE Description like '%shoes%'"

Comment: @Mac I think it really depends on the use case. UUIDv7 for example (which didn't exist when you posted this comment) solves the index-locality problem with regards to performant indexing, while also providing the same "time-sortable" property that autoincrementing bigints get you. The encoding of a time value into the identifier might also be useful for forensic reasons.

Comment: @pmarreck Yes, indeed. But note that UUIDv7s are still 4 times bigger than an integer, so there's still that. And they don't exist on Sql Server, around which this question (and this answer) dances. Sequential UUIDs are even better against fragmentation than UUIDv7s, but they are discoverable (which I guess doesn't matter much in the case of event sourcing). But then, incrementing integers are still a better choice on every aspect in this case...

Answer (score 11):

The GitHub project [CQRS.NET](https://chinchilla-software-com.github.io/CQRS/) has a few concrete examples of how you could do EventStores in a few different technologies. At time of writing there is an implementation in [SQL using Linq2SQL](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Cqrs/Events/SqlEventStore.cs) and a [SQL schema](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Cqrs/tools/EventStoreTable-SqlServer.sql) to go with it, there's one for [MongoDB](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Cqrs.MongoDB/Events/MongoDbEventStore.cs), one for [DocumentDB](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Azure/Cqrs.Azure.DocumentDb/Events/AzureDocumentDbEventStore.cs) (CosmosDB if you're in Azure) and one using [EventStore](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Cqrs.EventStore/EventStore.cs) (as mentioned above). There's more in Azure like Table Storage and Blob storage which is very similar to flat file storage.

I guess the main point here is that they all conform to the same principal/contract. They all store information in a single place/container/table, they use metadata to identify one event from another and 'just' store the whole event as it was - in some cases serialised, in supporting technologies, as it was. So depending on if you pick a document database, relational database or even flat file, there's several different ways to all reach the same intent of an event store (it's useful if you change you mind at any point and find you need to migrate or support more than one storage technology).

As a developer on the project I can share some insights on some of the choices we made.

Firstly we found (even with unique UUIDs/GUIDs instead of integers) for many reasons sequential IDs occur for strategic reasons, thus just having an ID wasn't unique enough for a key, so we merged our main ID key column with the data/object type to create what should be a truly (in the sense of your application) unique key. I know some people say you don't need to store it, but that will depend on if you are greenfield or having to co-exist with existing systems.

We stuck with a single container/table/collection for maintainability reasons, but we did play around with a separate table per entity/object. We found in practise that meant either the application needed "CREATE" permissions (which generally speaking is not a good idea... generally, there's always exceptions/exclusions) or each time a new entity/object came into existence or was deployed, new storage containers/tables/collections needed to be made. We found this was painfully slow for local development and problematic for production deployments. You may not, but that was our real-world experience.

Another things to remember is that asking action X to happen may result in many different events occurring, thus knowing all the events generated by a command/event/what ever is useful. They may also be across different object types e.g. pushing "buy" in a shopping cart may trigger account and warehousing events to fire. A consuming application may want to know all of this, so we added a CorrelationId. This meant a consumer could ask for all events raised as a result of their request. You'll see that in the [schema](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Cqrs/tools/EventStoreTable-SqlServer.sql).

Specifically with SQL, we found that performance really became a bottleneck if indexes and partitions weren't adequately used. Remember events will needs to be streamed in reverse order if you are using snapshots. We tried a few different indexes and found that in practise, some additional indexes were needed for debugging in-production real-world applications. Again you'll see that in the [schema](https://github.com/Chinchilla-Software-Com/CQRS/blob/master/Framework/Cqrs/tools/EventStoreTable-SqlServer.sql).

Other in-production metadata was useful during production based investigations, timestamps gave us insight into the order in which events were persisted vs raised. That gave us some assistance on a particularly heavily event driven system that raised vast quantities of events, giving us information about the performance of things like networks and the systems distribution across the network.

Comment: That's great, thanks. As it happens, long since writing this question, I've built a few myself as part of my Inforigami.Regalo library on github. RavenDB, SQL Server and EventStore implementations. Wondered about doing a file-based one, for a laugh. :)

Comment: Cheers. I added the answer mainly for others who come across it in more recent times and share some of the lessons learnt, rather than just the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Well you might wanna give a look at Datomic.

Datomic is a database of flexible, ***time-based facts***, supporting queries and joins, with elastic scalability, and ACID transactions.

I wrote a detailed answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105851/favoring-immutability-in-database-design/200226#200226)

You can watch a talk from Stuart Halloway explaining the design of Datomic [here](http://at.pscdn.net/008/00102/videoplatform/kv/121105techconf_close.html)

Since Datomic stores facts in time, you can use it for event sourcing use cases, and so much more.

Answer (score 2):

I think solution (1 & 2) can become a problem very quickly as your domain model evolves. New fields are created, some change meaning, and some can become no longer used. Eventually your table will have dozens of nullable fields, and loading the events will be mess.

Also, remember that the event store should be used only for writes, you only query it to load the events, not the properties of the aggregate. They are separate things (that is the essence of CQRS).

Solution 3 what people usually do, there are many ways to acomplish that.

As example, [EventFlow CQRS](https://eventflow.readthedocs.io/) when used with SQL Server creates a table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventFlow](
    [GlobalSequenceNumber] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BatchId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AggregateId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [AggregateName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Metadata] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [AggregateSequenceNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventFlow] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GlobalSequenceNumber] ASC
)
```

where:

- **GlobalSequenceNumber**: Simple global identification, may be used for ordering or identifying the missing events when you create your projection (readmodel).
- **BatchId**: An identification of the group of events that where inserted atomically (TBH, have no idea why this would be usefull)
- **AggregateId**: Identification of the aggregate
- **Data**: Serialized event
- **Metadata**: Other usefull information from event (e.g. event type used for deserialize, timestamp, originator id from command, etc.)
- **AggregateSequenceNumber**: Sequence number within the same aggregate (this is usefull if you cannot have writes happening out of order, so you use this field to for optimistic concurrency)

However, if you are creating from scratch I would recomend following the YAGNI principle, and creating with the minimal required fields for your use case.

Comment: I would argue that BatchId might potentially be related to CorrelationId and CausationId. Used to figure out what caused events, and string them together if need be.

Comment: It could be. However it this is so, It would make sense to provide a way to customize it (e.g. setting as the id of the request), but the framework does not do that.

Comment: I'd postulate that BatchId would potentially be used in coordinating transactions/rollbacks perhaps across multiple aggregates?

Answer (score 1):

Possible hint is design followed by "Slowly Changing Dimension" (type=2) should help you to cover:

- order of events occurring (via surrogate key)
- durability of each state (valid from - valid to)

Left fold function should be also okay to implement, but you need to think of future query complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon this would be a late answer but I would like to point out that using RDBMS as event sourcing storage is totally possible if your throughput requirement is not high.  I would just show you examples of an event-sourcing ledger I build to illustrate.

https://github.com/andrewkkchan/client-ledger-service
The above is an event sourcing ledger web service.
https://github.com/andrewkkchan/client-ledger-core-db
And the above I use RDBMS to compute states so you can enjoy all the advantages coming with a RDBMS like transaction support.
https://github.com/andrewkkchan/client-ledger-core-memory
And I have another consumer to be processing in memory to handle bursts.

One would argue the actual event store above still lives in Kafka-- as RDBMS is slow for inserting especially when the inserting is always appending.

I hope the code help give you an illustration apart from the very good theoretical answers already provided for this question.

Comment: Thanks. I've long since built a SQL-based implementation. I'm not sure why an RDBMS is slow for inserts unless you've made an inefficient choice for a clustered key somewhere. Append-only should be fine.